# Ambient noise levels in desert and recording studio

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, noise

Are there mathematical models which suggest which of the two - desert or recording studio - is likely to be quieter? I would think a recording studio would be quieter than a desert. Is there a mathematical model which suggests this?

Comment: Not quite sure what kind of desert you're referring to (a lot of deserts are pretty windy and not that quiet, especially if you're in a tent and hear a coyote howl, but that's a different story) – and what kind of recording studio, either! You'll need to be a bit more specific, please.

Comment: Are you talking about background noise levels? I don't know what kind of mathematical model you have in mind - you simply measure it. [This publication](https://www.nps.gov/grca/learn/nature/upload/sample-site.pdf) for example cites 15-30 dBA. For recording studios, anything around 25 dBA is good enough. Anyway, anything around 15 dBA is already equivalent to self-noise of most professional measurement microphones. If you could clarify your question maybe you might get a good answer.

Comment: If it's a desert with predators you'll hear roars, then screams, then thumping, then chewing.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a mathematical model which suggests this?

No. Background noise levels in recording studios and outside vary a lot from situation to situation. Outside is typically quite loud but if there is no wind, no air movement, no animal noises, and no traffic/planes/machinery/power lines levels can drop quite low.

Studios are equally variable. Some are designed to be very quiet inside, others are not.